# Can I launch a URL in browser, from scheduler, unless the URL is already open in a tab in the default browser

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm using the task scheduler in Windows to launch a page in the default browser at a particular time each day.

The problem I have is that if the page is already open in the browser, it will open that page again. Which I would like to prevent. For example. If I'm away from the computer for a few days, I come back to the computer to see many tabs open with the same page.

If I use the scheduler to run a batch file that can test for the existence of a tab in the browser before launching the URL, but I don't know how I can do that test.

Comment: So, I guess this was an [XY Problem question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and now we know what “X” is. You might want to think about totally different approaches. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … For example, do you control the web page? (I.e., is it on a web server that you control?) If so, you might be able to put some JavaScript in the page that sets a semaphore; i.e., checks some sort of global flag (DOM object? Cookie?): if it’s set, close the window, otherwise set the flag. If you don’t control the page, maybe you can wrap it with a web page that you do control: have it do the semaphore thing, and then (conditionally) load the real page (maybe in a frame). I don’t know the details, but maybe this will inspire somebody.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me what an XY Problem is. Never new it had a name.

No, I don't have control over the web page and don't want to get into iframe'ing it or writing much code. I was wondering if there might be something useful to use off the shelf, rather than build it on my own.

Comment: Glad I could educate you a little.  One last idea: `netstat | find` to see whether your machine has an ESTABLISHED connection to the web server.  Yes, this is a lousy idea.  On the one hand, it will indicate TRUE if your machine is connected to _any_ page on that server.  On the other hand, it might indicate FALSE in the very case you're concerned about — if the browser connected to the URL 24 hours ago, I don't know whether the connection is guaranteed to still be open.  The server probably closes connections that have been idle for a long time.  OK, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [TASKLIST](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)

example:

```
TASKLIST /v /fi "STATUS eq WINDOW-TITLE-HERE"
```

Comment: Almost there, but not quite.  Works fine if the current tab in my browser is the one I'm looking for, but if there are multiple tabs in the browser and the one I want to know exists, but is not the selected tab, I don't think I can find it with this tool.

Comment: It is really hard to find a tab, because every programming language, framework handles tabbing differently. example google chrome creates new thread for each tab opened.

Comment: Well, there are only so many browsers that are popularly used. IE, Firefox, Chrome, ...  If there isn't a general purpose method for enumerating child windows (at the Windows API level) for a browser, you can always special case the one or two that might be different. But I'm not looking for a programming solution here. I was hoping for a command-line utility that can identify that a browser tab might exist. Tasklist almost did the trick, but just didn't go deep enough for my use.